# Spring Boot app not running properly on Azure

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application, built to a war file. The code is [here](https://github.com/stealthrabbi/spring-boot-mvc-test). The application works properly when running locally in `./gradlew bootrun`, and my REST endpoints are responsive.

I set up FTP credentials on my azure site (Windows resource), and I've successfully uploaded the war file via the deploywar endpoint, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip).

When I FTP in to the site, I see the war file exploded in to /site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/. However, it's unclear to me how to access the site.

THe main URL is https://springboottest01.azurewebsites.net/, which still is serving the hostingstart.html. If I go to https://springboottest01.azurewebsites.net/webapps/ROOT/, I pull down my webapp's index.html, and a few JS files. However, the REST API call that it tries to make, /students/list, fails to run (404 error), which makes me think that the spring boot backend isn't actually running.

How do I diagnose this? What do I need to do to get this to work?

I also tried setting up a Linux resource (Tomcat 8.5) and deploying the webapp to that site. When I do that, I get the same problems there (in this case, the webapp is available at the root URL of that resource, but the REST endpoint that it tries to call fails). https://springboottest02.azurewebsites.net/